# How can I make a set up file to install my Sinhala Keyboard using Keyman Developer?

Tags: compiler-errors, keyboard, windows-installer

I have developed a Sinhala Keyboard using Keyman Developer 14.290. I have compiled it to a 'KMP' package file. I use it in my computer and shared with several friends. I thought of making a SET UP file for the installation. However when I tried to use the button "Compile Installer", it fails. Error message is "No .msi file"

1. Is it possible to make an installation file, like a SET UP file?
2. What other resources must I get, like the missing .msi file, to make it a success?

Tutorials do not cover installation file please.

I am using the Keyman Developer 14.291 in Windows 10 environment.

Thanks for your help please.

Answer (score 0):

According to KeyMan help they have a tool called the distribution editor which generates a WiX project based on your project. This can then be built as an MSI.

https://help.keyman.com/developer/engine/desktop/9.0/tutorials/distribution/

However it seems to use WiX 2.0 which is VERY, VERY old.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Painter. I will try that approach.